# headerFilterParams for exact string

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I'm using Tabulator in a project and I'm trying to use a `headerFilter` and `headerFilterParams:{values:true}` parameter for filtering one of the columns, but the filter seems to apply an "includes" filter to a string instead of an "equals" filter. This results in extra rows of data that are not intended based on the filter. Is there a way to change this behavior?
[image]

Comment: Try adding `headerFilterFunc: "="` to your column definition.